# Use value directly in script

Tags: powershell

I have the following script. The issue i have is that i need to create a value before using the information gathered from the csv file. The first code is what works for me, the second code is how i would want to use it, where the value $uid is not create before

```
   $users = import-csv c:\temp\users.csv
foreach ($user in $users){ 
$uid= $user.UserPrincipalName+":\calendar" 
add-mailboxfolderpermission -identity $uid -user "calendar_reviewer" -AccessRights LimitedDetails 
}


$users = import-csv c:\temp\users.csv
foreach ($user in $users){ 
add-mailboxfolderpermission -identity $user.UserPrincipalName+":\calendar" -user "calendar_reviewer" -AccessRights LimitedDetails 
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Im not understanding what you're asking for

Comment: So in other words you just don't want to assign the `$uid` variable first for it to work?

Comment: You can use a sub-expression if I'm understanding you correctly: `$($User.UserPrincipalName):\calendar"`. You can even assign it at the start of `$user` in your `foreach` loop. `foreach($user in $User.UserPrincipalName){ ...add-mailboxfolderpermission -identity "${User}:\calender"...}`

Comment: hi @AbrahamZinala 
when i dont create the value $uid, the code gives me an error when using the line "add-mailboxfolderpermission -identity $user.UserPrincipalName+":\calendar" -user "calendar_reviewer" -AccessRights LimitedDetails". I cant add the string ".\calendar" to the variable $user.userprincipalname, so thats why i create the value $uid before running the command "add-mailboxfolderpermission"
What i want to know is how i can type, so that i do not need to create the value $uid before
Please let me know if its still unclear

Comment: My guess: use parenthesis, `add-mailboxfolderpermission -identity ($user.UserPrincipalName+":\calendar") -user "calendar_reviewer" -AccessRights LimitedDetails`

Comment: You didn't run my suggestions. What I comment should work.

Comment: `"$($User.UserPrincipalName):\calendar"` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, your string composition isn't working like you're expecting it to.

If we use the following test function it'll demonstrate what's happening:

```
function Invoke-MyFunction
{
    param( $Identity, $OtherParams )
    write-host "identity    = '$Identity'";
    write-host "otherparams = '$OtherParams'";
}
```

In your first (working) example, PowerShell *is* concatenating the strings:

```
$uid = $user.UserPrincipalName+":\calendar"

Invoke-MyFunction -Identity $uid
# identity    = 'myname:\calendar'
# otherparams = ''
```

but in your broken sample, it's not treating the `$user.UserPrincipalName+":\calendar"` as a *single expression* - it's treating `+":\calendar"` as a separate string that it passes as a second [positional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1#position-argument) parameter:

```
Invoke-MyFunction -Identity $user.UserPrincipalName+":\calendar"
# identity    = 'myname'
# otherparams = '+:\calendar'
```

There's a few different ways to get PowerShell to treat your parameter as an expression so it evaluates it before passing the value as a parameter:

**Grouping Operator**

As recommended by @zilog80 in the comments, wrap it in the [Grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#grouping-operator--) (i.e. `( ... )`) to force PowerShell to evaluate the expression before passing the result into the parameter:

```
Invoke-MyFunction -Identity ($user.UserPrincipalName+":\calendar")
# identity    = 'myname:\calendar'
# otherparams = ''
```

**String Interpolation**

Per @Abraham Zinala's comment, use string interpolation (note the use of the [Subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#subexpression-operator--) (i.e. `$( ... )` to substitute in the value of `$User.UserPrincipalName`)

```
Invoke-MyFunction -Identity "$($User.UserPrincipalName):\calendar"
# identity    = 'myname:\calendar'
# otherparams = ''
```

**Assign to a variable**

As you've already found, you can force the expression to be evaluated by assigning it to a temporary variable, then pass the variable as a parameter:

```
$uid = $user.UserPrincipalName+":\calendar"

Invoke-MyFunction -Identity $uid
# identity    = 'myname:\calendar'
# otherparams = ''
```